# Not able to write unit test cases in angular using jasmine karma for this function

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am very new to unit testing . my project is on angular 12 . i am not able to write unit test cases for this complex function. please help out.

...

```
   private saveConversionRecords(cookieValue: string, userId: string)
   { 
    let cookies = JSON.parse(cookieValue);
    let cookie: Conversion = new Conversion();
    cookie = cookies[cookies.length - 1];

     if(userId)
     {    
     cookie.lpVersion = 3;
     this.userService.saveConversion(userId, cookie).subscribe(data => 
     {});
     this.cookieService.delete('conv');
     }
   }




export class Conversion{
userId: string
source: string
category: string
keyword: string
landingPage: string
matchType: string
placement: string
target: string
adPosition: string
ad: string
lpVersion: number
conversionDate: Date
}



     public saveConversion(userId: string, conversion: Conversion): 
     Observable<number>{
     return this.http.post<number>(environment.baseUrl + 'auth/' + 
     'SaveConversion?userId=' + userId, conversion);
     }



      delete(name: string, path?: string, domain?: string): void;



      fdescribe('LoginFormComponent', () => {
          let component: LoginFormComponent;
          let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginFormComponent>;

           beforeEach(async(() => {
           TestBed.configureTestingModule({
           imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule,],
           declarations: [ LoginFormComponent ],
           providers: 
           [AuthService,UserService,LoaderService,CookieService]
           })
           .compileComponents();
           }));

            beforeEach(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginFormComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            fixture.detectChanges();
            });
```

...

Please help out ,  i am stuck at this middle of project .  just give me overview  or idea , how to write the unit test cases for this function.

Comment: You need to provide more information, i.e. provide your unit test and test setup. Looking at the function, you definitely need to provide the services `userService` and `cookieService` as mocks to the test suite, otherwise the test will fail.

Comment: I updated the question and provided unit test setup.

Comment: what kind of error do you get running the test suite? atm you are only providing the test env. in your `fdescribe` but you are not testing anything

Comment: Not able to write testCase only .  not getting any idea how to start ? can u please help me out in writing sample unit test case.